# how to add searchable functionality to custom listview that gets data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i am using custom list view to display data from database...
here is below the website that i have referenced...  but am trying to add search functionality  to the custom list view
http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html
here is the code

```
DbHelper.java

package com.hk.sqlitedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_LNAME+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}


//activity to add recored
AddActivity.java

package com.hk.sqlitedemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button btn_save;
private EditText edit_first,edit_last;
private DbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private String id,fname,lname;
private boolean isUpdate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_activity);

        btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        edit_first=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.frst_editTxt);
        edit_last=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.last_editTxt);

       isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if(isUpdate)
        {
            id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
            fname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Fname");
            lname=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Lname");
            edit_first.setText(fname);
            edit_last.setText(lname);

        }

         btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);

         mHelper=new DbHelper(this);

    }

    // saveButton click event
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fname=edit_first.getText().toString().trim();
        lname=edit_last.getText().toString().trim();
        if(fname.length()>0 && lname.length()>0)
        {
            saveData();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AddActivity.this);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            alertBuilder.create().show();
        }

    }

    /**
     * save data into SQLite
     */
    private void saveData(){
        dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,fname);
        values.put(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME,lname );

        System.out.println("");
        if(isUpdate)
        {   
            //update database with new data
            dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //insert data into database
            dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        //close database
        dataBase.close();
        finish();


    }

}

//activity to display record in list
DisplayActivity.java

package com.hk.sqlitedemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

    private DbHelper mHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

    private ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> user_lName = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ListView userList;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_activity);

        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);

        mHelper = new DbHelper(this);

        //add new record
        findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("update", false);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //click to update data
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Fname", user_fName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("Lname", user_lName.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", userId.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //long click to delete data
        userList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {

                build = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayActivity.this);
                build.setTitle("Delete " + user_fName.get(arg2) + " " + user_lName.get(arg2));
                build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
                build.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                                        user_fName.get(arg2) + " "
                                                + user_lName.get(arg2)
                                                + " is deleted.", 3000).show();

                                dataBase.delete(
                                        DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                        DbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                                + userId.get(arg2), null);
                                displayData();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                build.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = build.create();
                alert.show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * displays data from SQLite
     */
    private void displayData() {
        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

        userId.clear();
        user_fName.clear();
        user_lName.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                user_fName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_FNAME)));
                user_lName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_LNAME)));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(DisplayActivity.this,userId, user_fName, user_lName);
        userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();
    }



}

//adapter to load data into list
DisplayAdapter.java

package com.hk.sqlitedemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> firstName;
    private ArrayList<String> lastName;


    public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> fname, ArrayList<String> lname) {
        this.mContext = c;

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            mHolder.txt_fName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_fName);
            mHolder.txt_lName = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_lName);
            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_fName.setText(firstName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_lName.setText(lastName.get(pos));

        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_fName;
        TextView txt_lName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The search functionality is done using android default SearchView.OnQueryTextListener. Please refer the below code sample

if (mListSearch != null) {
            mListSearch .setQueryHint("Search");
            mListSearch.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

```
        queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                listadapter.filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return true;
            }
        };
        mgalleryListSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    }
    mgalleryListSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mgalleryListSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        }
    });
```

use the below filter method in adapter class

```
    public voidfilter(String charText) {

    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    mListModel.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        mListModel.addAll(arraylist);
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<ListModel> list=new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListModel wp : arraylist)
        {
            if (wp.getalbumName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(charText))
            {
                mListModel.add(wp);

            }
        }

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: please could you be more specific, that is to my code above

Comment: Get the data list from the sqlite database and set it to the list view, then by using the queryTextListener( above code) filter the list by the text which entered in the search view by using adapter.filter(txt) method.

Comment: is filter() a method? if it is where can i find it